# Curve goes in different directions

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a single path as mesh and after I've converted it into a path there are some vertices going in the wrong direction.

For example at the top right and at the bottom in the middle there is also some weird things going on as seen in the lower picture.

If I apply a bevel object it looks a bit weird as you can tell.

Is there a way that all vertices have the same direction?

Here you can download the [file](https://www.mediafire.com/?pf1b20w9vynt8nj)
Please don't mind the Audi R8 and the German names of the layers.

[image]

Comment: can you upload the blend file?

Comment: @Vader sure! it's already uploaded

Comment: do you still have the original mesh before you converted it to a curve? I think the problem should be fixed at that level before you convert it.

Comment: No Sorry i don't have it any more

Comment: well i f you had it: make sure you do Ctrl+Alt+Shift+M in edit mode. This select all non-manifold vertices, the ones you need to fix. Also remove doubles, make sure the threshold is high enough to get rid of all non-manifold vertices. Ctrl+N to recalculate the normals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curve is going in different directions because there are gaps in the curves. In your case there are several point where the curve has a gap. It looks like it is a single continous curve but actually there are 2 end points on top of each other that only make it look like a single curve.
You can fix this by moving on of the overlapping endpoints away form the other and than filling it, use <kbd>F</kbd> to connect to points. The direction of the curve will then automatically be normalized. Just to be sure: when you are done with that you can also normalize the curve using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]   [image]

How to find these overlapping points:
To find these point you can in *Edit* mode, hover of a point with the mouse and hit <kbd>L</kbd>. This will select all the connected points. You can than select the end points manually.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought I proofed this but it seems I wasn't accurate enough. Thanks. And what does the normalize function do.